# Как ускорить перебор строк?

Tags: python, строки, list

Как ускорить перебор строк по началу в списке?

```
data = [str(x) for x in range(1000000)]
string = "145723"


for i in data:
    if i.startswith(string):
        ...
```

Какой алгоритм может ускорить этот процесс? (без нумбы)

Answer (score 1):

Не надо перебирать лишние элементы и не надо перебирать строки:

```
def numbers(n, m):
    k = 1
    while m < n:
        yield from range(m, m + k)
        m *= 10
        k *= 10


for i in numbers(10000000, 145723):
    print(i)
```

> ```
> $ python numbers.py
> 145723
> 1457230
> 1457231
> 1457232
> 1457233
> 1457234
> 1457235
> 1457236
> 1457237
> 1457238
> 1457239
> ```